# Stream huge data per second with java

Tags: java, algorithm, parallel-processing, terminal, javac

I have 10000 textfiles with this structure

```
x         y  
------------------ text file structure

2         1
3         2
3         3
.         .
.         .
.         .
```

As can i send 10000 data (one second information is a line of file) per second in java? I want to emulate a 10000 gps's

Thanks for help.

Comment: How do you want to send this data? As files? As a webservice call? Over a network port?

Comment: Read a line per file and send the line info per second, maybe json encode ... over a network port using rabbitmq is a possible solution

Comment: Does the file have to be read in real-time or can it be preprocessed?

Comment: It can be preprocessed for a json structure and after that send the info, but with 10000 files i really dont know how to emulate it, maybe run a program in java at the same time for each file ... uhmm problems with buffer?

Comment: may the question make sense, and I will come back.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that once per second you want to read one line from 10,000 different files.

A problem you will have is that some OSes don't allow to have 10,000 files open at once and openning and closing files repeatedly is very inefficient.

One way around this is to merge the files, or increase the maximum files allowed.

Since you are emulating the GPSes, you need to communicate the same way they do. e.g. if that use JSon and rabbitmq, use those. But if they don't use those, you will be making the mulation less realistic.

Reading 10,000 lines per second from open files shouldn't be a problem.

Do the files have the actual timestamps e.g. in milli-seconds or micro-seconds, so you can order the events as they happened?

Comment: Yeah, the files have a second time third column, then the efficient way is merge the files and after that, order the events, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have an update per second, you would be better off with a more accurate time stamp as you have no may of knowing the order difference sources gave you their data.